# list as value of hashMap in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

File:

```
Person1:AP
Person2:AP
Person3:KE
Person4:KE
Person5:UK
Person6:AP
Person7:UK
Person8:AP
```

What I have tried is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestNull {

    public static void main ( String args[]) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader("/home/username/Desktop/test"));
        String str;
        HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();

        try {
            while ( (str = br.readLine()) != null)  {
                String[] s = str.split(":");
                h.put(s[1],s[0]);
            }
            System.out.println(h);
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException E) {   
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
        finally {   
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I could achieve this by Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (FILE,"test");

my %hash=();
while (my $line = <FILE>)   {
    
    chomp $line;
    
    my ($name,$country) = split(":", $line);
    
    chomp ($name,$country);
    
    $hash{$country} .= "$name ";    
}

for my $keys (keys %hash)   {
    
    print "$keys: $hash{$keys}\n";
    
}
```

From the data file, I am looking for an out put like this:

```
{
  AP = [person1, person2, person6, person8],
  KE = [person3, person4],
  UK = [person5, person7]
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

Following is what you need -

```
Map<String, List<String>> h = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

And for every line -

```
String[] s = str.split(":"); //s[1] should be the key, s[0] is what should go into the list 
List<String> l = h.get(s[1]); //see if you already have a list for current key
if(l == null) { //if not create one and put it in the map
    l = new ArrayList<String>();
    h.put(s[1], l);
}
l.add(s[0]); //add s[0] into the list for current key
```

Comment: Hint: OP's looking for `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap`. Read the desired output.

Comment: @gthm geeky: if the order (in which the lines are read) should be maintained  then just replace `new HashMap<String, List<String>>()` with `new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>()` as Luiggi suggested.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: OP's Perl example doesn't indicate that he wants to use a LinkedHashmap

Comment: @AdrianPronk I never said to check perl's code, instead output example.

Answer (score 2):

To turn that map upside down, you probably want this:

```
HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
...
// your reading code
...
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
...
for(String key: h.keySet()) {
    if(!map.hasKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    map.get(key).add(h.get(key));
}
```

and now "map" contains the desired structured data, with "AP" pointing to an arraylist (person1, person 2, person6, person8), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a good option could be: [How do I use the new computeIfAbsent function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278443/how-do-i-use-the-new-computeifabsent-function)

It would look like this:

```
HashMap<String, List<Atring>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<Line> lines = new ArrayList();

// read lines

for (Line line : lines){
     List<String> l = map.computeIfAbsent(line.getKey(), k -> new ArrayList<String>());
     l.add(line.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other solutions would be use one of the Multimap implementations from Guava.  It may be overkill to add such a dependency if this is the only such map you have, but if you wind up with a bunch of maps of this nature, it's nice not to have this boilerplate all over:

```
if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
  map.put(key, new List<Foo>());
}
map.get(key).add(value);
```

When you can just do:

```
multimap.put(key, value);
```

Instead.  There are a number of implementations depending on exactly what you want.

Sorted:
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html

Same order as you added them: 
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html

Don't care about ordering:
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap.put()` will replace whatever element you've already inserted into the hash map. You need to first try to retrieve an existing key in the map, and if it already exists (i.e., was inserted for a previous input line), then you can append the current name to its value, and re-insert it into the map.

Also, you're probably going to want to use something like `List<String>` to hold the map values (the names) instead of just a `String`. Using a list also saves you the need to re-insert the value, since you can just apppend to the list that is already in the map.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change the `while` and the type of the map:

```
Map<String, List<String>> h = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

/* (...) */

while ( (str = br.readLine()) != null)  {

    String[] s = str.split(":");
    list = h.get(s[1]);
    if(list==null) {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    list.add(s[0]);
    h.put(s[1],list);

}
```