# How do I use the new computeIfAbsent function?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8

I very much want to use [Map.computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) but it has been too long since lambdas in undergrad.

*Almost* directly from the docs: it gives an example of the old way to do things:

```
Map<String, Boolean> whoLetDogsOut = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
String key = "snoop";
if (whoLetDogsOut.get(key) == null) {
  Boolean isLetOut = tryToLetOut(key);
  if (isLetOut != null)
    map.putIfAbsent(key, isLetOut);
}
```

And the new way:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Value(f(k)));
```

But in their example, I think I'm not quite "getting it."  How would I transform the code to use the new lambda way of expressing this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand from the example there?

Comment: What is "k"?  Is it a variable being defined?  How about "new Value" - is that something from java 8, or representing an object I need to define or override?  whoLetDogsOut.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Boolean(tryToLetOut(k))) doesn't compile, so I'm missing something...

Comment: What exactly doesn't compile? What error does it produce?

Comment: Temp.java:26: error: illegal start of expression
    whoLetDogsOut.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Boolean(tryToLetOut(k)));  (pointing to the ">")

Comment: Compiles fine for me. Make sure that you really use Java 8 compiler. Do other Java 8 features work?

Comment: I *thought* I was: javac -version = javac 1.8.0-ea
And netbeans had source set to 1.8

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Suppose you have the following code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        Map<String, Boolean> whoLetDogsOut = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        whoLetDogsOut.computeIfAbsent("snoop", k -> f(k));
        whoLetDogsOut.computeIfAbsent("snoop", k -> f(k));
    }
    static boolean f(String s) {
        System.out.println("creating a value for \""+s+'"');
        return s.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Then you will see the message `creating a value for "snoop"` exactly once as on the second invocation of `computeIfAbsent` there is already a value for that key. The `k` in the lambda expression `k -> f(k)` is just a placeolder (parameter) for the key which the map will pass to your lambda for computing the value. So in the example the key is passed to the function invocation.

Alternatively you could write: `whoLetDogsOut.computeIfAbsent("snoop", k -> k.isEmpty());` to achieve the same result without a helper method (but you won’t see the debugging output then). And even simpler, as it is a simple delegation to an existing method you could write: `whoLetDogsOut.computeIfAbsent("snoop", String::isEmpty);` This delegation does not need any parameters to be written.

To be closer to the example in your question, you could write it as `whoLetDogsOut.computeIfAbsent("snoop", key -> tryToLetOut(key));` (it doesn’t matter whether you name the parameter `k` or `key`). Or write it as `whoLetDogsOut.computeIfAbsent("snoop", MyClass::tryToLetOut);` if `tryToLetOut` is `static` or `whoLetDogsOut.computeIfAbsent("snoop", this::tryToLetOut);` if `tryToLetOut` is an instance method.

Answer (score 144):

Recently I was playing with this method too. I wrote a memoized algorithm to calculate Fibonacci numbers which could serve as another illustration on how to use the method.

We can start by defining a map and putting the values in it for the base cases, namely, `fibonnaci(0)` and `fibonacci(1)`:

```
private static Map<Integer,Long> memo = new HashMap<>();
static {
   memo.put(0,0L); //fibonacci(0)
   memo.put(1,1L); //fibonacci(1)
}
```

And for the inductive step, all we have to do is redefine our Fibonacci function as follows:

```
public static long fibonacci(int x) {
   return memo.computeIfAbsent(x, n -> fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n-1));
}
```

As you can see, the method `computeIfAbsent` will use the provided lambda expression to calculate the Fibonacci number when the number is not present in the map. This represents a significant improvement over the traditional, tree recursive algorithm.

Comment: Nice, single-line conversion to dynamic programming.  Very slick.

Comment: You may get fewer recursive calls if you have the (n-2) call first?

Comment: You should be more cautious when you use computeIfAbsent recursively. For more details please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840047/recursive-concurrenthashmap-computeifabsent-call-never-terminates-bug-or-fea

Comment: is it still possible to set a cache lifetime?

Comment: This code results in `HashMap`'s internals being corrupted, just as in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8172951 and will fail with `ConcurrentModificationException` in Java 9 (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071667)

Comment: The docs literally say that *the mapping function should not modify this map during computation*, so this answer is clearly wrong.

Comment: @fps, Sorry, just trying to learn / understand. How is this modifying the map? Isn't it just adding value to a new key in the map which I assume is the purpose of computeIfAbsent?

Comment: @PunterVicky When you call `fibonaci(n-2)` and `fibonaci(n-1)` recursively, these calls result in new calls to `computeIfAbsent`, which internally modify the map, thus violating its contract

Answer (score 56):

Another example. When building a complex map of maps, the computeIfAbsent() method is a replacement for map's get() method. Through chaining of computeIfAbsent() calls together, missing containers are constructed on-the-fly by provided lambda expressions:

```
  // Stores regional movie ratings
  Map<String, Map<Integer, Set<String>>> regionalMovieRatings = new TreeMap<>();

  // This will throw NullPointerException!
  regionalMovieRatings.get("New York").get(5).add("Boyhood");

  // This will work
  regionalMovieRatings
    .computeIfAbsent("New York", region -> new TreeMap<>())
    .computeIfAbsent(5, rating -> new TreeSet<>())
    .add("Boyhood");
```

Answer (score 40):

## multi-map

This is really helpful if you want to create a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap)  without resorting to the [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) library for its implementation of [`MultiMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

For example, suppose you want to store a list of students who enrolled for a particular subject.

The normal solution for this using JDK library is:

```
Map<String,List<String>> studentListSubjectWise = new TreeMap<>();
List<String>lis = studentListSubjectWise.get("a");
if(lis == null) {
    lis = new ArrayList<>();
}
lis.add("John");

//continue....
```

Since it have some boilerplate code, people tend to use Guava `Mutltimap`.

Using Map.computeIfAbsent, we can write in a single line without guava Multimap as follows.

```
studentListSubjectWise.computeIfAbsent("a", (x -> new ArrayList<>())).add("John");
```

Stuart Marks & Brian Goetz did a good talk about this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uTVXxJjuco

Comment: Another way to make a multimap in Java 8 (and more concise) is to just do `studentListSubjectWise.stream().collect(Collectors.GroupingBy(subj::getSubjName, Collectors.toList());` This produces a multi-map of type `Map<T,List<T>` in JDK only more concisely imho.

Comment: Adding to the answer; the part about `computeIfAbsent` starts at 25:30

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this comparison example (old vs new) which demonstrates both the approaches;

```
static Map<String, Set<String>> playerSkills = new HashMap<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //desired output
    //player1, cricket, baseball
    //player2, swimming

    //old way
    add("Player1","cricket");
    add("Player2","swimming");
    add("Player1","baseball");
    
    System.out.println(playerSkills);

    //clear
    playerSkills.clear();
    
    //new
    addNew("Player1","cricket");
    addNew("Player2","swimming");
    addNew("Player1","baseball");
    System.out.println(playerSkills);
    
}

private static void add(String name, String skill) {
    Set<String> skills = playerSkills.get(name);
    if(skills==null) {
        skills= new HashSet<>();
        playerSkills.put(name, skills);
    }
    skills.add(skill);
}

private static void addNew(String name, String skill) {
    playerSkills
            .computeIfAbsent(name, set -> new HashSet<>())
            .add(skill);
}
```