# Android TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() producing strange strings

Tags: java, android, arraylist, timezone, baseadapter

I have an Android application which uses `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` to pull all available timezone ID strings. These IDs are saved to an `ArrayList`, as per the following:

```
ArrayList<String> clocks = new ArrayList<>();
String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
Collections.addAll(clocks, ids);
```

This ArrayList is used later on to populate a ListView using my custom BaseAdapter. There are a few entries that aren't particularly informative and I don't want them in the list, such as:

```
Etc/GMT+10
PST8PDT
NZ-CHAT
```

I added a for loop to go through all entries and remove any unwanted ones, at the moment I have the following checks for testing purposes:

```
String string = clocks.get(i);
String[] split = string.split("/");

if(string.equals("MST7MDT")) {
    clocks.remove(i);
}

if(string.contains("Etc/")) {
    clocks.remove(i);
}

if(split.length <= 1) {
    clocks.remove(i);
}

if(!string.contains("/")) {
    clocks.remove(i);
}
```

Now this should delete the one identical to "MST7MDT" (it doesn't), any containing "Etc/" (only about half of the `Etc/example` elements get deleted), and any that don't contain a "/" the split one should do the same (not all are deleted). I've tried it with `trim()` but it hasn't helped. It doesn't seem to be a problem with `remove(int)`, I tried passing the Object too but still nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated, has anyone else experienced problems with the results from `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`? Am I missing something stupid here?

Comment: May I recommend using jodatime instead of the Calendar object?

Comment: Its not the Calendar object that I'm having problems with, just TimeZone at the moment. I can see jodatime has its own TimeZone implementation also, might be worth giving it a go. Cheers.

Comment: Joda time has actually saved me a lot of headaches and inherent errors in the Calendar object.  Easy to use, understand and implement.

Comment: I don't see how Joda-Time can help in this concrete case because [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs()) will yield strings like "MST7MDT" or "Etc/...", too.

Answer (score 3):

## Keep zones, rather than discard

As we can see in the [list of time zone names on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), the zones have changed and evolved over the years. Many of the entries are mere alias for other zones. Some turned out to be an inadvertent duplicate of another zone. And many were ill-conceived and are now deprecated.

I suggest that rather than focusing on zones to delete, you focus on zones to keep. The rest of this Answer shows how.

> `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`

The `TimeZone` class was years ago supplanted by the `java.time.ZoneId` class. Never use the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `TimeZone`, `Date`, and `Calendar`.

## List of continents

As a first step in getting a cleaned-up list, I suggest filtering for those names that begin with one of these continents:

- Europe
- Africa
- Antarctica
- Atlantic
- America
- Pacific
- Indian
- Australia

And add an entry of `Etc/UTC` for when the user wants no time zone at all.

In Java code, sorted alphabetically.

```
List < String > zoneGroupNames = List.of(
        "Africa" ,
        "Antarctica" ,
        "Atlantic" ,
        "America" ,
        "Australia" ,
        "Europe" ,
        "Indian" ,
        "Pacific" ,
        "UTC"
);
```

I suggest you offer a two-step process for the user, where they suggest first a continent, then a zone.

## Multimap of zone group name to zone names

Build a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) of each zone group name to collection of zone id names. We need a map of the group name such as `Europe` to a list of the zone names such as `Europe/Berlin`, `Europe/London`, and `Europe/Malta`.

```
Map < String, List < String > > mapGroupNameToZoneNames = new TreeMap <>();
```

Mapping a key to a collection of values is known as a "multimap". We now have built-in multimap functionality with the `Map` implementations bundled with Java. Call [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) (see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694536/642706)).

```
Set < String > zoneIdStrings = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
for ( String zoneIdString : zoneIdStrings )
{
    String groupName = zoneIdString.split( "/" )[ 0 ];
    if ( zoneGroupNames.contains( groupName ) )
    {
        mapGroupNameToZoneNames.computeIfAbsent( groupName , ( x -> new ArrayList <>() ) ).add( zoneIdString );
    } // Else skip it.
}

System.out.println( "mapGroupNameToZoneNames = " + mapGroupNameToZoneNames );
```

Add that one entry for `Etc/UTC`.

```
mapGroupNameToZoneNames.computeIfAbsent( "Etc" , ( x -> new ArrayList <>() ) ).add( "UTC" );
```

## Present to user

Present that list of groups to the user. Say the user selects item # 6 (index 5), which is currently `Europe`.

```
String groupNameChosenByUser = zoneGroupNames.get( 5 ); // Europe
List < String > zoneNamesOfGroup = mapGroupNameToZoneNames.get( groupNameChosenByUser );
```

Present that list of zone names for that one group. Say the user selects item # 12 (index 11), which is currently `Europe/Malta`.

```
String zoneNameChosenByUser = zoneNamesOfGroup.get( 11 );  // Malta
```

Make a `ZoneId` object from the string of that zone name.

```
ZoneId zoneIdChosenByUser = ZoneId.of( zoneNameChosenByUser );
```

> zoneIdChosenByUser.toString() = Europe/Malta

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).