# Recursive ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent() call never terminates. Bug or "feature"?

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, concurrenthashmap

Some time ago, [I've blogged about a Java 8 functional way of calculating fibonacci numbers recursively](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/02/28/java-8-friday-goodies-easy-as-pie-local-caching), with a `ConcurrentHashMap` cache and the new, useful `computeIfAbsent()` method:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Test {
    static Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
            "f(" + 8 + ") = " + fibonacci(8));
    }

    static int fibonacci(int i) {
        if (i == 0)
            return i;

        if (i == 1)
            return 1;

        return cache.computeIfAbsent(i, (key) -> {
            System.out.println(
                "Slow calculation of " + key);

            return fibonacci(i - 2) + fibonacci(i - 1);
        });
    }
}
```

I chose `ConcurrentHashMap` because I was thinking of making this example even more sophisticated by introducing parallelism (which I didn't in the end).

Now, let's increase the number from `8` to `25` and observe what happens:

```
        System.out.println(
            "f(" + 25 + ") = " + fibonacci(25));
```

The program never halts. Inside the method, there's a loop that just runs forever:

```
for (Node<K,V>[] tab = table;;) {
    // ...
}
```

I'm using:

```
C:\Users\Lukas>java -version
java version "1.8.0_40-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-ea-b23)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

[Matthias, a reader of that blog post also confirmed the issue (he actually found it)](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/02/28/java-8-friday-goodies-easy-as-pie-local-caching/#comment-121821).

This is weird. I would have expected any of the following two:

- It works
- It throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`

But just never halting? That seems dangerous. Is it a bug? Or did I misunderstand some contract?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is fixed in [JDK-8062841](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062841).

In the [2011 proposal](http://jsr166-concurrency.10961.n7.nabble.com/ConcurrentHashMapV8-td7312.html), I identified this issue during the code review. The JavaDoc was updated and a temporary fix was added. It was removed in a further rewrite due to performance issues.

In the [2014 discussion](http://jsr166-concurrency.10961.n7.nabble.com/Re-ConcurrentHashMap-computeIfAbsent-td11687.html), we explored ways to better detect and fail. Note that some of the discussion was taken offline to private email for considering the low-level changes. While not every case can be covered, the common cases will not livelock. These [fixes](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/main/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java?r1=1.258&r2=1.259) are in Doug's repository but have not made it into a JDK release.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for sharing! My report was also accepted as [JDK-8074374](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8074374)

Comment: @Ben sorry for offtop, but I'm really surprised of how low SO rating you have despite so significant contribution in knowledge base concerning such complicated thing as lock-free (and close to lock-free) concurrency.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Thanks. I often provide a quick answer in comments instead of a spending the time on a longer, full answer. Comment scores don't increase reputation, though. I probably have a less than average interest in chasing rep, though.

Comment: @Ben not quite fixed: [boom](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vr6q209dd6ifcwo/ConcurrentHashMapTest.java)

Comment: @ScottMcKinney nice catch! It looks like the same assertion could be applied to `transfer` and it was a missed case. Can you email `concurrency-interest@cs.oswego.edu` to get Doug's attention?

Comment: @Ben sure, no prob.  I found this after integrating caffeine into my cache backend where the cache loader can be recursive.  My first attempt at fixing this was to set the cache's initial capacity to the cache size.  This fixes most of the problems including the test I linked to above, however I'm afraid there are still more missed cases beyond that one.  I will try to isolate them and provide narrow tests.

Comment: @ScottMcKinney An ugly but [possible workaround](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Faq#recursive-computations) in Caffeine is to use `AsyncLoadingCache` so that the computations are performed outside of the map operation (on the future), optionally with the `synchronous()` view.

Comment: @Ben thanks for the suggestion.  I've resorted to using a Cache instead of a LoadingCache, where my facade class wraps the Cache and the CacheLoader, its get() method delegates to Cache#getIfPresent() / put(), calling the CacheLoader when needed. _shrug_

Answer (score 63):

This is of course a *"feature"*. The [`ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) Javadoc reads:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null. The entire method invocation is performed atomically, so the function is applied at most once per key. Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple, and ***must not attempt to update any other mappings of this map***.

The *"must not"* wording is a clear contract, which my algorithm violated, although not for the same concurrency reasons.

What's still interesting is that there is no `ConcurrentModificationException`. Instead, the program just never halts - which still is a rather dangerous bug in my opinion (i.e. [infinite loops. or: anything that can possibly go wrong, does](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/01/16/infinite-loops-or-anything-that-can-possibly-go-wrong-does/)).

#### Note:

The [`HashMap.computeIfAbsent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) or [`Map.computeIfAbsent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) Javadoc don't forbid such recursive computation, which is of course ridiculous as the type of the cache is `Map<Integer, Integer>`, not `ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>`. It is very dangerous for subtypes to drastically re-define super type contracts (`Set` vs. `SortedSet` is greeting). **It should thus be forbidden also in super types, to perform such recursion.**

Comment: Good find. I'd suggest a bug report/RFE against JDK.

Comment: Done, let's see if it is accepted... I'll update with a link if it is.

Comment: It seems likely to me that this type of recursive modification of other mappings is not allowed in `ConcurrentHashMap` because of the other important part of its contract: "**The entire method invocation is performed atomically, so the function is applied at most once per key.**" It is likely that your program, by violating the "no recursive modifiction" contract, is attempting to acquire a lock it already holds, and is deadlocking with itself, not running in an infinite loop.

Comment: From the JavaDoc: `IllegalStateException - if the computation detectably attempts a recursive update to this map that would otherwise never complete`

Comment: @murgatroid99: That's rather implicit. The method invocation could still be performed atomically *and* update several keys. Although that probably wouldn't be a good idea in a concurrent context, because of deadlock potential.

Comment: @Axel: The report was accepted as [JDK-8074374](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8074374). It is probably a duplicate of [JDK-8062841](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062841), as documented by [Ben Manes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28845674/521799)

Comment: @Lukas: it seems to me that if invocation is to stay atomic and still be able to update several keys than  probably all segments of map would need to be locked

Comment: @user62058: In my opinion, that should be fine. Of course, it might lead to a dead-lock, which would be equally bad as a non-terminating loop

Comment: @Lukas you suggest to use HashMap, is the put method on HashMap thread-safe? so is it guaranteed to not corrupt the map state when invoked simultanously by multiple threads? with corrupt i mean that you have a "lost update" or an exception on put. Its ok if two threads compute the same value and only one put operation of those threads really is updating the map (for example last one wins)

Comment: @leozilla: See the original question. In this case, the algorithm is single-threaded.

Comment: @LukasEder even with `HashMap` it's not OK. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8172951

Comment: @LukasEder that's good, but i think your final "note" might still be understood as "... but for `HashMap` it works". Let's rephrase it: "even though `Map` javadocs do not explicitly forbid that, the function should not modify the map in any way"

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen: Do you want me to add some interrobang after the final sentence in bold? :)

Answer (score 4):

This is very similar to the bug.
Because, if you create your cache with capacity 32, your program will work until 49.
And it is interesting, that parameter sizeCtl =32 + (32 >>> 1) + 1) =49!
May be the reason in resizing?

Comment: I don't have time to dig through the source code, but I think that you are right. We are hitting this in production, constantly. As soon as we increased the `CHM` initial capacity to a very high figure, this went away. Until we can refactor our code, this is what we will do...