# Share variables between classes using Map (as Cache)

Tags: java, caching, hashmap

I would like to implement a common cache variable storage in order to share between classes. I have many classes because I use cucumber java webdriver and it is necessary to share between steps, page objects/classes.

I have the class

```
public class Cache {
    private HashMap<String, String> cache = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public HashMap<String, String> getCache() {
        return cache;
    }
}
```

But the question, what is the most efficient way to set the key-value pairs?

My idea would be use a getter to get and use the stored variables such as cache.get("KEY") and I get the value. How to store variables in efficient way in this cache?

Any example code would be appreciated.

Comment: Err, put()? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-

Answer (score 0):

1. When using 'cache.set(key,val)', the obvious efficiency factor is
   the selection of key and [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Choosing_a_hash_function) . However, in 99%
   percent of my projects it was efficient enough to use a
   straight-forward, intuitive String key (e.g. if your business requires to cache books by publisher+title, then "penguin_prideAndPrejudice" might do fine).
   However, the only way to know for sure is to test it on a data sample!

   2. As a side note, though it wasn't your original question, I'd suggest considering thread safely (HashMap isn't thread safe, so for concurrent environments consider synchronization or ConcurrentHashMap - just [beware of bugs in some versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840047/recursive-concurrenthashmap-computeifabsent-call-never-terminates-bug-or-fea))
   3. There are 3rd party caches, such as [Guava](http://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache) , that might help with advanced caching considerations, e.g. expiration.