# Filter out duplicates for CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java-stream, distinct, completable-future

I wanna to filter out the duplicates after the first `CompletableFuture` and then invoke the second stage using another `CompletableFuture`. What I tried:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FunctionWithExceptions<T, R, E extends Exception> {
    R process(T t) throws E;
}


public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(FunctionWithExceptions<? super T, ?, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> {
        String key = "";
        try {
            key = (String) keyExtractor.process(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Get instanceIp failed!");
        }
        return seen.add(key);
    };
}

List<CompletableFuture<InstanceDo>> instanceFutures = podNames.stream()
            .map(podName -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(RethrowExceptionUtil.rethrowSupplier(() -> {
                PodDo podDo = getPodRetriever().getPod(envId, podName);
                podDoList.add(podDo);
                return podDo;
            }), executor))
            .map(future -> future.thenApply(podDo -> podDo.getInstanceName()))
            .filter(distinctByKey(CompletableFuture::get))
            .map(future -> future.thenCompose(instanceName ->
                    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> get(envId, instanceName), executor)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you can see, the `distinctByKey` will **invoke** `get` which will directly make the **concurrency** to **sequentiality**.

What should I do to make it **CONCURRENT** again but meantime retain the **distinct** feature?

**OR**

I only have one choice?

To wait the whole **first stage** to complete and then start the **second stage**?

Comment: Be careful, `thenApply` and `thenCompose` are synchronous. You would probably prefer `thenApplyAsync` and `thenComposeAsync`.

Comment: @kagmole Thanks for the reply. But I do **not** think you get the point here. I know pretty well about the **\*Async** since they're well documented. I want the **second** just run after the **first** and **thenCompose** here is quite enough since it will work in the same thread as the **first** stage.

Comment: I see, and there is still indeed the `distinctByKey` problem. I may have a suggestion, based on `Optional`, but I fear it will end up unnecessarily bloated.

Comment: @kagmole Thanks for the **idea**, I will have a try. B.T.W it's the **distinct** problem from the very beginning actually. Hahah, thank you, man.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was not very clear. :)

Comment: @kagmole Not a problem, man. What do you think of my **solution** below. Have some ideas to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a simple demo to solve this kind of issue, but I really **don't** know whether it's reliable or not. But at least it makes sure the **second** stage can be accelerated using `Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();`.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> intFutures = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i+1)
                .limit(5)
                .map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    int a = runStage1(i);
                    if (seen.add(a)) {
                        return a;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }}))
                .map(future -> future.thenCompose(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        return runStage2(i);
                    } else {
                        return i;
                    }})))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for (CompletableFuture<Integer> future: intFutures) {
                resultList.add(future.join());
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
            out.println("Future failed!");
        }
        resultList.stream().forEach(out::println);
    }

    private static Integer runStage1(int a) {
        out.println("stage - 1: " + a);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500 + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt()) % 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Integer.valueOf(a % 3);
    }

    private static Integer runStage2(int b) {
        out.println("stage - 2: " + b);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200 + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt()) % 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Integer.valueOf(b);
    }
```

By returning **special** values in the **first** stage when it's **duplicated** and then in the **second** stage, via the **special** value (-1), I can ignore the time-consuming second-stage computation.

The output indeed filter out some **redundant** computation of the **second stage**.

```
stage - 1: 0
stage - 1: 1
stage - 1: 2
stage - 1: 3
stage - 2: 2 // 
stage - 2: 1 //
stage - 1: 4
0
1
2
-1
-1
```

I think it's not a good solution. But what can I optimise to make it better?

Comment: Why do you think it is not a good solution? The only issue I see is that the resulting list contains a mix of the results of the first stage (the `-1`) and the second stage, but you can easily filter them out.

Comment: You should use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` instead of `new Random()` as it is thread-safe and the preferred alternative. Your solution is similar to what I was thinking, you just used a discriminator value `-1` instead of `Optional`, which is nice if you can do it (no `Optional` overhead). I don't see an improvement right now though.

Comment: @kagmole Thanks for the help, I got the point and improved it in this way. Besides, thanks for the soft reminder using **thread-safe** random, which I forgot. Thank you ~

Comment: @DidierL Thanks for the point, I just tested them and it seems good. What I thought is that it could be more elegant - filtering out directly instead of checking it in the second stage and then filter.

Answer (score 0):

A small improvement compared to [your submitted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50471520/525036) might be to use the `ConcurrentHashMap` as a kind of cache, so that your final list contains the same results independently of the order you got them in:

```
Map<Integer, CompletableFuture<Integer>> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> intFutures = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
        .limit(5)
        .map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> runStage1(i)))
        .map(cf -> cf.thenCompose(result ->
                seen.computeIfAbsent(
                        result, res -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> runStage2(res))
                )
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that it is important that the function passed to `computeIfAbsent()` immediately returns (so using a `supplyAsync()` for example), because it keeps a lock inside the map while being executed. In addition, this function must not attempt to modify the `seen` map because [it could cause issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28840047/525036).

With this change the output could be for example:

```
stage - 1: 1
stage - 1: 0
stage - 1: 2
stage - 2: 1
stage - 2: 2
stage - 1: 3
stage - 2: 0
stage - 1: 4
0
1
2
0
1
```

Additionally, this allows to inspect the `seen` map after all futures have been completed in order to get the unique results.