# How can I call binarySearch() on my Entry class?

Tags: java, indexing, binary-search, comparable, user-defined

I'm making a book index where I have an inner class called Entry which holds a String (the word itself) and an Integer TreeSet to hold all the line numbers the word appears on.

I have a ListIndex class (which holds the Entry class) where I create an ArrayList of type Entry. When I add a word to the list, I need to check whether the word is already in the list by using binarySearch(). However, I can't use Collections.binarySearch(myList, word) because the ArrayList is of type Entry.

My Entry class implements Comparable  but I still don't understand how I can fix this. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show simple example?

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Are you trying to check that an `Entry` object exists (regardless of line numbers)? Or are you trying to see if an `Entry` object exists AND has at least one entry in its `TreeSet` of line numbers? Are you just looking for a entry for a word, or are you trying to insert a line number into the `TreeSet`. You need to more thoroughly think through your scenario.

Comment: Does `Entry` consist of anything more than `String` and a `TreeSet`? If not, you would be better off using a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

## Use bogus `Entry` object as criterion

Assuming your implementation on `Entry` for the `compareTo` method required by the `Comparable` interface merely defers to its contained `String` object’s `compareTo` method and ignores the state of the `TreeSet` of line numbers…

Just instantiate a bogus `Entry` object with your target string. Use that `Entry` object just for [`Collections.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,T)), then discard.

```
Entry target = new Entry( "Widget" , new TreeSet<Integer>() ) ;
int index = Collections.binarySearch( myList , target ) ;  // Assuming the `compareTo` method compares only the `String` member field while ignoring the `TreeSet` member field.
if( entry < 0 ) { … no entry yet exists … }
else  // Else, entry found to exist.
{ 
    Entry entry = myList.get( index ) ;
    …
}
…
// As `target` goes out of scope, the object becomes a candidate for garbage collection, to be deleted from memory eventually.
```

To send the `target` object to garbage collection faster, reassign `target = null ;` after the binary search.

## Use `Map` instead of `Entry` class

If your `Entry` class is nothing more than a `String` and a `TreeSet`, then I suggest you skip defining that class at all. Use `Map` instead. The key is a `String` for the index entry word(s), and the value is a `TreeSet`.

```
Map< String , TreeSet< Integer > > entries = new TreeMap<>() ;
```

To search for an entry, use [`Map::containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) and pass the index entry word(s).

### Multimap behavior

You can then use Java 8 [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) method to get convenient [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) behavior for easy access to the set of line numbers. Demonstrated on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694536/642706).

Or use a 3rd-party multimap implementation. For example, the [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) library

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @user11610667 You are welcome. Please take a moment to edit your Question, to make it more clear. See my Comments on the Question. Thousands of people may be reading your Question over the years ahead, so make it most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `Comparable` interface in `Entry` like this

```
static class Entry implements Comparable {

        String text;
        TreeSet<Integer> set;

        public Entry(String text, TreeSet<Integer> set) {
            this.text = text;
            this.set = set;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof String)
                return text.compareTo((String) obj);
            else {
                Entry otherEntry = (Entry) obj;
                return text.compareTo(otherEntry.text);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new Entry("bbbb", new TreeSet<>()));
        entries.add(new Entry("aaaa", new TreeSet<>()));
        entries.add(new Entry("cccc", new TreeSet<>()));
        entries.add(new Entry("hhhh", new TreeSet<>()));
        entries.add(new Entry("dddd", new TreeSet<>()));

        Collections.sort(entries);
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(entries, "cccc", (e1, e2) -> e1.compareTo(e2));
        System.out.println(index);
    }
```

, output

```
2
```

Comment: Could you approve the answer :)